# Trouble installing GHDL in Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, installation, vhd

I have tried the whole day to install GHDL in my PC so that I could compile my .vhd file and test it with Gtkwave.

One of my trials was typing

`sudo apt-get install ghdl gtkwave`

I got this:

Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
O pacote ghdl não está disponível, mas é referenciado por outro pacote.
Isto pode significar que o pacote está faltando, ficou obsoleto ou
está disponível somente a partir de outra fonte

And this is the error message:

```
E: O pacote ghdl não tem candidato para instalação
```

For the ones that do not speak portuguese, it is saying that the package ghdl does not have a candidate for installation, but I really don't know what to do with that information.

Does anyone have a clue of what I should do to have the GHDL command working and to install Gtkwave?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GHDL is not officially supported any more since Ubuntu 18.04. You're left with a couple of options:

- Build it yourself. Bash script[1] to streamline the process is available.
- Use docker image (ghdl/ext). See https://github.com/ghdl/docker

[1] https://gist.github.com/mathieucaroff/73ccbd30638d9b37b7129a7b7b8d7726